# What happened with the relocating allocator?

Tags: c, gnu, glibc

I was reading old glibc documentation [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_3.html) when I saw three strange functions that I had never seen before (r_alloc, r_alloc_free and r_re_alloc). They implemented an allocator that realocates memory for defragmentation purposes, I think, but I can't find more info anywhere else.

Can you tell me more about that functions? Are they still in Glibc? If not, why they were removed?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, undocumented functions are for "internal" use. Even if they're not removed _yet_, they might be removed, renamed or altered in any future version, as the internal design of glibc evolves.

Comment: @MSalters The functions are neither internal, nor undocumented: the question asks about functions found in (old) *documentation*.

Comment: If you want copying or compacting garbage collection, C is probably not the language for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you tell me more about that functions?

What do you want to know about them? They are pretty clearly described in the manual in which you've found them.

They are somewhat similar to Win32 `LocalAlloc` and `LocalLock` -- you get a handle to memory object, but to get the usable address of that object requires an extra step. These are generally a bad idea, except on extremely memory constrained systems.

> Are they still in Glibc?

No.

> If not, why they were removed?

Because they are generally a bad idea, and breed to hard-to-find bugs.

**Update:**

> What kind of bugs are possible by using something like that?

Here is an example:

```
const char *my_strcat(const char *a, const char *b)
{
  const size_t len_a = strlen(a);
  const size_t len_b = strlen(b);
  char *handle;

  if (r_alloc((void**)&handle, len_a + len_b + 1) == NULL) return NULL;
  memcpy(handle, a, len_a);
  memcpy(handle + len_a, b, len_b + 1);

  return handle;
}

// There are memory leaks here. Ignore them for now.
int main()
{
  const char *result = my_strcat("abc", my_strcat("def", "ghi"));

  return strcmp(result, "abcdefghi");
}
```

Can you spot the bug?

The program will sometimes succeed, sometimes fail with non-zero exit code, and sometimes crash with `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: I tried digging up a changelog entry mentioning the removal, but I can't seem to find one. Do you know where the change was announced?

Comment: @dfeuer They were not part of the original import of glibc-2.0. I am guessing they are a glibc-1.x artifact.

Comment: ¿Can you explain why they are a bad idea? ¿What kind of bugs are possible by using something like that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Can you spot the bug?"  Other than not NUL-terminating the resulting string?  That bug is possible with standard `malloc()`, too.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewHenle The string is properly NUL-terminated. *That* bug isn't there.

Comment: The bug, as I see it, is that the handle is in the stack. In this case it doesn't matter: because you don't call any allocating function, the pointer can't be moved. But in a more complex scenario, it could lead to disaster. However, I think that with careful programming you can avoid the problems, as like in normal C code. But I'm not sure if defragmentation is still a problem in modern PCs, so I won't try to use anything similar for now :-).

Comment: @Mabus No, you have not yet found *the* bug. Note that there are two calls to `r_alloc`, and think about what the second call may do to memory allocated with the first.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that there are TWO calls. But the bug is the same think I saw: as the handle is in the stack, if the memory moves, the pointer is updated and this position in the stack is overwritten and probably something is corrupted. Am I right?

Comment: @Mabus No, the handle being on the stack isn't a problem. The fact that you still haven't found the bug should serve as a nice illustration for why `r_alloc` is hard to use correctly ;-)

Comment: It *is* a problem, because r_alloc store a pointer to the variable, for modifying it latter when the memory moves. Maybe the bug that you say is that when you return the value it is a fixed pointer, and won't change when memory moves, it is?

Comment: @Mabus You are right, there is *that* problem as well. So there are actually two separate bugs here. You've found one I didn't think of, but not yet the one I intended to illustrate. Actually, your last statement is pointing to that second bug.